# Compare two FixMessages in QuickFIXJ

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol

I need to compare two fix messages (say two ExecutionReports) in QuickFIXJ.

Let's call them `er1` and `er2`

Now, what I mean by comparing them is that a bunch of fields must be identical.
for instance I care that tag 55, tag 207, tag 1 are the same.
but not others.

It seems to me that the only way to do so is to write something as expensive (performance-wise) as this:

```
public static boolean compare(ExecutionReport er1,ExecutionReport er2) 
{
   StringField sf1 = new StringField(55);
   StringField sf2 = new StringField(55);

   er.getField(sf1);
   er.getField(sf2);

   if (sf1.getValue().equals(sf2.getValue())==false) return false;

   ... // continue with all of the other fields
   ... // in the same way

}
```

Am I missing something ?
can somebody suggest a better/faster approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no function to compare two fix messages in the [API](https://www.quickfixj.org/javadoc/1.6.4/), it seems. But instead of comparing the whole message fields, the best would be to compare only those fields which are mandatory. An extension would be if you are dead sure those fields would be present in the FIX message.

Another option would be to compare in a thread different than the one for the session where you are sending and receiving messages. It would be hard to decide if the messages need to be compared in the same thread, without knowing what happens downstream with the Execution reports or what are your actions if the Execution reports match.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation based on `quickfix.Message.toXML()` iteration logic.
Result of the comparison is sorted map of composite key (if field is part of the group) and pair of 'before' and 'after' state.

```
import static java.lang.Math.min;
import static java.util.Collections.emptySet;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils.subtract;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;

import quickfix.Field;
import quickfix.FieldMap;
import quickfix.Group;
import quickfix.Message;

public class FixDiff {

    private static final CompositeKeyComparator COMPARATOR = new CompositeKeyComparator();

    private Set<Integer> ignored;

    public FixDiff() {
        this(emptySet());
    }

    public FixDiff(Set<Integer> ignored) {
        this.ignored = ignored;
    }

    public Map<List<Integer>, Pair<String, String>> compare(Message expected, Message actual) {
        Map<List<Integer>, String> expectedMap = toHierarchialMap(expected);
        Map<List<Integer>, String> actualMap = toHierarchialMap(actual);

        Collection<List<Integer>> missing = subtract(expectedMap.keySet(), actualMap.keySet());
        Collection<List<Integer>> extra = subtract(actualMap.keySet(), expectedMap.keySet());
        Collection<List<Integer>> diff = expectedMap.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> !missing.contains(e.getKey()) && !extra.contains(e.getKey()))
                .filter(e -> !e.getValue().equals(actualMap.get(e.getKey())))
                .map(Entry::getKey)
                .collect(toList());

        TreeMap<List<Integer>, Pair<String, String>> discrepancies = new TreeMap<List<Integer>, Pair<String, String>>(COMPARATOR);
        missing.forEach(key -> discrepancies.put(key, new ImmutablePair<String, String>(expectedMap.get(key), null)));
        extra.forEach(key -> discrepancies.put(key, new ImmutablePair<String, String>(null, actualMap.get(key))));
        diff.forEach(key -> discrepancies.put(key, new ImmutablePair<String, String>(expectedMap.get(key), actualMap.get(key))));
        return discrepancies;
    }

    private Map<List<Integer>, String> toHierarchialMap(Message message) {
        Map<List<Integer>, String> result = new HashMap<List<Integer>, String>();
        toHierarchialMap(result, new ArrayList<Integer>(), message.getHeader());
        toHierarchialMap(result, new ArrayList<Integer>(), message);
        toHierarchialMap(result, new ArrayList<Integer>(), message.getTrailer());
        return result;
    }

    private void toHierarchialMap(Map<List<Integer>, String> map, ArrayList<Integer> segmentKey, FieldMap segment) {
        Iterator<Field<?>> iterator = segment.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Field<?> field = iterator.next();
            if (!ignored.contains(field.getTag()) && field.getObject() != null)
                map.put(compositeKey(segmentKey, field.getTag()), field.getObject().toString());
        }
        Iterator<Integer> groupKeyIterator = segment.groupKeyIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Integer groupKey = groupKeyIterator.next();
            if (ignored.contains(groupKey))
                continue;
            for (Group group : segment.getGroups(groupKey))
                toHierarchialMap(map, compositeKey(segmentKey, groupKey), group);
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Integer> compositeKey(ArrayList<Integer> parent, Integer tag) {
        ArrayList<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<>(parent);
        copy.add(tag);
        return copy;
    }

    private static class CompositeKeyComparator implements Comparator<List<Integer>> {
        @Override
        public int compare(List<Integer> o1, List<Integer> o2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < min(o1.size(), o2.size()); i++) {
                if (o1.get(i) != o2.get(i))
                    return o1.get(i) - o2.get(i);
            }
            return o1.size() - o2.size();
        }
    }
}
```